# MQ MFT With Powershell

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

IBM WS MQ7.5, windows MQMFT agent, linux MQ manager.

I am trying to run a powershell script as defined in the xml of a MQ mft ant script.

I configured the path to the powershell scripts in commandPath of the agent.properties files.

The managed call starts but fails

```
<fte:presrc command="C:\IBM\MFT\script\MoveFileToArchive.ps1" successrc="0">
               <fte:arg value="${base.file}"/>
            </fte:presrc>
```

The error reads

> cannot run program createprocess error=193 MoveFileToArchive.ps1 is not a valid win32 application

I tried to add the path to powershell with powershell.exe defined like so

```
<fte:presrc command="C:\windows\system\windowspowershell\v.1.0\powershell.exe C:\IBM\MFT\script\MoveFileToArchive.ps1" successrc="0">
               <fte:arg value="${base.file}"/>
            </fte:presrc>
```

This doesnt work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen from the error, MFT agent is using `CreateProcess` API to start a program. `CreateProcess` API can run only executable file. The `Powershell` script you are using is a non executable. Hence the error.

If you want to be able to open any file with its associated application then you need `ShellExecute` instead of `CreateProcess`. But this is not under your control. So need to look for alternative?

Try using a batch file say `ps.cmd` and in the batch file you run the PowerShell script like

```
Powershell -executionpolicy bypass -File C:\IBM\MFT\script\MoveFileToArchive.ps1 %1
```

Where %1 would be the argument for PS script.

The Ant script also needs bit of a change.

```
    <fte:presrc command="ps.cmd" successrc="0">
       <fte:arg value="${base.file}"/>
    </fte:presrc>
```

I am sure you have already set the `commandPath` property to a suitable value in agent.properties.

Give it a try.